# Is there any programming language similar to TeX?

Tags: tex-core, languages, programming

I know nothing about programming, so TeXMaker's pseudo-WYSIWYG reminded me of a stereotypical programmer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I'm not really sure this question is on-topic here. In fact, I'm not really sure what your question is. The title is probably answerable, though I don't think it really belongs here (P.S. TeX is Turing-complete). But the body of your question has me a little confused about what you want

Comment: TeXmaker is ***not*** WYSIWYG - not even pseudo-WYSIWYG (whatever that means). How can a programme remind you of a programmer, stereotypical or otherwise? I mean, presumably you are at least familiar enough with programming to know that programmers are typically people? But the answer to the title is 'Yes. TeX is a programming language similar to TeX.' Does that answer the question?

Comment: It isn't, but a WYSIWYG illusion can be sustained with the built in pdf viewer and a fast-refreshing quick build.  


It has a dark mode, autocompletes commands, has different text colors, and is easier to use if some of the code is indented. It resembles an actual programming software.  


Yes, that answers the question. But it spawns another. Do you know of *another* language that is also similar to TeX?

Comment: This may be of interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language

Comment: @onewhaleid TeX is far more than a markup language :-) This question could use some work, though – what exactly is being asked? Do you perhaps want to know what languages TeX may have been based on or languages that could be based on TeX? [Curl may be a similar language if you squint your eyes a bit.](http://exploringdata.github.io/vis/programming-languages-influence-network/#TeX) I've found a few similarities with functional languages (and the functional style in general). What is it exactly that you're asking?